# Cannot access error while creating a document in an open cmis based server

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I have been trying to create a document inside an existing folder using the Open CMIS chemistry server.

While doing so i always get this error

Cannot access `https://test.com/json/cc5646c4e12341020012fc05/root?objectId=oRZQrt4ApnNx6fj6hAZ-4rW3wp8MGpgiZ6bvQgnUmDQ": null`

The folder id (under which i am trying to create a document )is correct which is as given in the url oRZQrt4ApnNx6fj6hAZ-4rW3wp8MGpgiZ6bvQgnUmDQ.
I am not an admin of the server, do i need to have some write rights ?..not able to find the actual cause.

UPDATE: Stack trace which is coming

```
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968): Error ERROR_CONNECT_FAILURE in metadata thread processing task (repository cc5646c4e12341020012fc05, High, DocumentUpload, Document: [oRZQrt4ApnNx6fj6hAZ-4rW3wp8MGpgiZ6bvQgnUmDQ, 1388583206977])
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968): org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Cannot access "https://mobiledocs-mcm.hana.ondemand.com/mcm/b/json/cc5646c4e12341020012fc05/root?objectId=oRZQrt4ApnNx6fj6hAZ-4rW3wp8MGpgiZ6bvQgnUmDQ": null
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.invoke(AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.java:305)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.invokePOST(AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.java:86)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.browser.AbstractBrowserBindingService.post(AbstractBrowserBindingService.java:358)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.browser.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:83)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:841)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:75)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:449)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at com.test.mcm.MetadataDownloadThread.createDocumentOnServer(MetadataDownloadThread.java:549)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at com.test.mcm.MetadataDownloadThread.run(MetadataDownloadThread.java:235)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.invoke(AbstractApacheClientHttpInvoker.java:256)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    ... 8 more
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:420)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-01 19:04:16.825: E/MetadataDownloadThread(18968):    ... 11 more
```

The same url when i do  a post through chrome i get the following json response.

```
{
    "exception": "permissionDenied",
    "message": "INVALID_TOKEN_PROVIDED"
}
```

Thanks and Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are you connecting to a SAP Mobile Documents server. Could you provide a stacktrace of the exception?

If you want to test from a web browser, you have to provide an extra token. Please see the SAP Mobile Documents documentation for details.

Comment: Hi Florian...thanks for the reply...i have updated the post with the stack trace

Comment: For some reason you cannot POST to the server. Make sure your network and proxy configurations are correct. Also check your authentication and cookie settings.

Comment: yepp....get is working fine with i am able to fetch the content...checked my cookie settings even...does my user id need any special permission to post or upload a document?...but again with my browser client i am able to perform post..i am using this api to create document on the server Document createDocument(Map<String, ?> properties, ContentStream contentStream, VersioningState versioningState);

Comment: Turn on logging for the Apache HTTP client. The cause of this problem is obviously not in the exception, but should be logged.

Comment: Hi Florian...thanks for the comments. There was some problem with application code which was causing the problem